# Is the concept of dual vectors an essential concept in the geometry of Physics?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, tensors

I've just started with the book "Modern Classical Physics" by Blandford and Thorne. It has the interesting premise of explaining classical physics from a (coordinate-free where possible) geometric viewpoint. One thing that always confuses me is that there are so many different ways folks present geometric frameworks.

I scoped out whether some terms were present or not. Tensors form an essential part of the book, and yet tensors are defined as "rank $n$" objects that map $n$ vectors to a real number. There's no mention of covectors/dual vectors, multilinear maps or expression of tensor rank as $(m,n)$.

So before I invest my time in the 1500-page book, I'd like some guidance from the community here - how essential is the concept of dual vectors (not just classical, but beyond as well since I'll end up applying these concepts in any further learning I do) in Physics? Is the notion of tensors with just one number instead of a pair of numbers specifying the rank too limited, or is it perfectly okay? Is it important to make the distinction between vectors and dual vectors in Physics fields - will I be severely limiting myself if I can't make that distinction?

Comment: Yes, understanding dual vectors is very important, and I'd say not just in more advanced theories like GR. Even in classical mechanics (eg the moment of inertia tensor) or introductory classical electrodynamics, which is so much more cleanly formulated using the language of differential forms (I mean the amount of time introductory E&M courses spend on teach vector calculus of div,grad,curl, laplacians etc could be just as well spent teaching the exterior calculus of differential forms, to much better gain).

Comment: Also, not carefully understanding/clarifying the definitions and meaning of vectors (elements of a vector space $V$), covectors/dual-vectors (elements of the dual space $V^*$) vs their components relative to a specific basis, and also not clarifying how an inner product induces an isomorphism $V \to V^*$ is the source of soooooooooo many confusions. Also, learning about vectors and covectors isn't that hard, just a little patience, and the right book to build a strong basic foundation.

Comment: I'd say this is the easiest part, because this all comes down to linear algebra. Everything is linear :), and linear = simpl(er) (well...usually) Calculus (and calculus on manifolds) is the hard part, because you're dealing with non-linear things. And the whole idea of calculus is to approximate (in some sense) non-linear things by linear things (be it functions or even the spaces themselves). So of course, it is well worth the effort to study carefully linear (and multi-linear) things, before moving on to the non-linear stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on which kinds of physics you are interested in. For more theoretical and geometrical branches of physics yes, you want the full notion of a tensor. A possible definition of a tensor is as a multilinear map from $k$ copies of a vector space $V$ and $l$ copies of its dual $V^*$ to the field of scalars, usually $\mathbb{R}$. That is where the pair of numbers you refer to is coming from.

If you have an inner product on $V$ you get a canonical isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ so you can blur the distinction between the two of them and that is probably what the book is doing.

The concept of a dual vector is pretty important, and it is a special case of a tensor I'd definitely recommend learning about it.

Comment: Hmm, thought so. Thanks so much! One thing - what exactly do you mean by "more theoretical and geometrical branches"? My plan is to learn up to GR and QFT for sure. Do these qualify? Or did you mean even more advanced branches like candidates for quantum gravity?

Comment: Dual vector anything in theoretical physics really. And for GR you want the general notion of a tensor yes. Good physicists oriented references are Nakahara 'Geometry topology and physics" and, for GR but with quite a few chapters on geometry, Misner Thorne and Wheeler Gravitation. There are surely many others, it's a popular topic with many good books.

Comment: And as for inner product, the book lists some quantities as "fundamental" - these include scalar, vector, the notion of dot product, metric tensor (which is essentially a rank 2 tensor mapping 2 vectors to the dot product). So I guess inner product is implicit in the treatment and you're right about them blurring the line between vectors and their duals.

Comment: One last thing: Apparently Nakahara's book is very dense. Are there any alternative references, to your knowledge, that address the notion of tensors accepting both vectors and dual vectors, and which make that distinction?